# Program sadly crashes and I have no clue why

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, function-definition

Does anyone know why this program crashes at "printf", I have no idea to be honest, thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC96i.png)

---

Added from comments:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 

typedef struct{ 
    char *content; 
}DATABASE;

DATABASE *database; 

void example(DATABASE *db){ 

    db = malloc(sizeof(DATABASE));
    db[0].content = calloc(6,1); 
    memcpy(db[0].content,"hello",6);
}

void main(){ 

    example(database); //it crashes here!!! 
    printf("%s\n",database[0].content); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include your code as text and not as an image.

Comment: @gravechest Why do you have decided that the program sadly crashes? Maybe it happily crashes.:)

Comment: @gravechest Move the code from the comment to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the pointer `database` declared in the file scope is initialized as a null pointer.

It is passed to the function `example` by value. That is the function deals with a copy of the value of the pointer `database`. Changes of the copy within the function do not reflect on the value of the pointer itself. So dereferencing the null pointer results in undefined behavior.

You need to pass the pointer by reference indirectly through a pointer to it (pointer to pointer). Dereferencing the pointer within the function you will get a direct access to the value of the original pointer.

For example

```
void example(DATABASE **db){ 

    *db = malloc(sizeof(DATABASE));
    ( *db )->content = calloc(6,1); 
    memcpy( ( *db )->content,"hello",6);
}


//...

example( &database );
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: Side issue of `main()`  omits the C spec "or in some other implementation-defined manner" possibility that may allow `void main()`.  IAC, that issue not needed here.

Answer (score 2):

When the call `example(database)` is made the variable `database` is uninitialized. Also THE COPY of this variable (which is a pointer) is passed to the function. Inside the function this COPY is initialized, but the copy goes out of scope at the end of the function. When the call to `printf` is made the variable `database` has the original uninitialized value.

Make an effort to learn how to debug your code step by step. It will make the programming a lot easier for you.

Comment: Ah, yes that was the problem, Thanks for the help and have a good day.